# Non-intrusive Conda installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I would like to install miniconda and have access to Conda's packages, specifically `sfepy`. However I don't want it to take over my current Python definitions. I see Conda as just another Python environment among the many which I can and do use.

Initially I tried to deactivate both options when installing miniconda as shown below.

[image]

When the installation was done I added the miniconda path to a temporary `cmd`, navigated to the directory containing `conda.exe`, and tried to install `sfepy`

```
set PATH=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2;%PATH%
cd C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\Scripts
conda install sfepy
```

This gives an error `ImportError: cannot import name requests`. I know that I am using the right Python distribution because when I type `python` I get the following in `cmd`

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Which is the Anaconda distribution. What is further amazing is that now I have no problem importing `requests` package by typing

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests
<module 'requests' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Plaxis\PLAXIS 2D\plxscripting\requests\__init__.pyc'>
```

However as you can see it is importing it from another Python installation. Also I know that `requests is included with the` conda` installation as shown below:

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\Scripts>dir C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\Lib\site-packages
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 944A-AABE

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\Lib\site-packages

02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          .
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          ..
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          adodbapi
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          asn1crypto
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          certifi
20-Apr-18  01:53             3,019 certifi-2018.04.16-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          cffi
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          cffi-1.11.5-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          chardet
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          concurrent
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          conda
14-May-18  15:56             9,440 conda-4.5.4-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          conda_env
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          cryptography
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          cryptography-2.2.2-py2.7.egg-info
31-May-18  22:08               126 easy_install.py
31-May-18  22:09               300 easy_install.pyc
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          enum
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          futures-3.2.0-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          idna
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          idna-2.6-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          ipaddress-1.0.22-py2.7.egg-info
15-Apr-18  21:00            79,852 ipaddress.py
17-Apr-18  17:20            73,435 ipaddress.pyc
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          isapi
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          menuinst
30-May-18  05:08             1,157 menuinst-1.4.14-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          OpenSSL
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          pip
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pkg_resources
30-Oct-17  13:41             6,512 pycosat-0.6.3-py2.7.egg-info
30-Oct-17  13:41            86,528 pycosat.pyd
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pycparser
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pycparser-2.18-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pyOpenSSL-18.0.0.dist-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          PySocks-1.6.8-py2.7.egg-info
09-May-18  03:25               138 pythoncom.py
02-Sep-18  10:45               259 pythoncom.pyc
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pythonwin
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pywin32-223-py2.7.egg-info
09-May-18  03:26               630 pywin32.pth
09-May-18  03:35                 5 pywin32.version.txt
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          pywin32_system32
30-Apr-18  01:47               119 README
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          requests
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          ruamel_yaml
05-Jun-18  18:29               935 ruamel_yaml-0.15.37-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          setuptools
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          setuptools-39.2.0-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg-info
17-Sep-17  21:46            30,888 six.py
21-Oct-17  21:32            29,588 six.pyc
21-Dec-17  07:05            32,281 socks.py
27-Feb-18  19:36            26,492 socks.pyc
21-Dec-17  07:05             2,913 sockshandler.py
27-Feb-18  19:36             4,345 sockshandler.pyc
30-Oct-17  13:41             8,806 test_pycosat.py
30-Oct-17  13:41            14,512 test_pycosat.pyc
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          urllib3
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          urllib3-1.22-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          wheel
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          wheel-0.31.1-py2.7.egg-info
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          win32
02-Sep-18  10:45    <DIR>          win32com
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          win32comext
19-Sep-17  22:23             5,785 wincertstore-0.2-py2.7.egg-info
19-Sep-17  22:23            11,873 wincertstore.py
19-Sep-17  22:23            13,141 wincertstore.pyc
20-Sep-17  04:01               863 win_inet_pton-1.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
30-Aug-14  10:58             2,753 win_inet_pton.py
20-Sep-17  04:01             2,452 win_inet_pton.pyc
02-Sep-18  10:44    <DIR>          xonsh
06-Mar-18  21:23           164,864 _cffi_backend.pyd
              30 File(s)        614,011 bytes
              48 Dir(s)  38,983,368,704 bytes free
```

I just don't know why its getting it first from another directory.

I really don't want to have to define the path variables as I go. Is there some way I can generate a temporary environment from within `cmd` that can define all the environment variables for me whenever I need it? I don't want Conda to take over my system Python...

Comment: Use Anaconda Prompt?